# Swift 5 UIView has no UIResponder

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiresponder

Here is the sample source code:

**ViewController**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view = Home()
    }

}
```

**Home**

```
class Home: UIView {
    ...
    func parent() -> UIViewController {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self.next
        while responder != nil {
            if let c = responder as? UIViewController { return c }
            else { responder = responder?.next }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

For the line

```
var responder: UIResponder? = self.next
```

The `responder` is always nil, that I cannot get the ViewController.

Something strange is that, I got no problem with the same function for all the subviews of `Home`.

Comment: See the doc of `next`, the discussion part: `For example, UIView implements this method and returns the UIViewController object that manages it (if it has one) or its superview (if it doesn’t).`. So for its subviews it's normal, since default would be their superview. Now, I wonder how does it know what's the ViewController of the view... Could the issue be there?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When are you calling `parent()`?

Comment: @Sweeper I was trying to add `navigationItem` to the parent controller when `init()` the `Home` view.

Comment: @Larme Temporarily, I skipped this problem by passing the `ViewController`'s `self` to `Home`'s constructor, and it's working fine. However, I'm wondering why the `next`, which is supposed to be the `ViewController`, is still nil.